# Python: how to use numpy fill_diagonals on matrices of zeros in list comprehension?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, list-comprehension, diagonal

The following code gives my desired output format with the exception of lacking 1's across the diagonals.

`>>> xlist = [2,3]`
`>>>[{'key': np.zeros(shape=(4, x, x))} for x in xlist]`

This is the current output:

```
Out[610]: [{'key': array([[[ 0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.]],
  
         [[ 0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.]],

  
     [[ 0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.]],
  
     [[ 0.,  0.],
      [ 0.,  0.]]])}, 

{'key': array([[[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
      
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
      
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]],
      
         [[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
          [ 0.,  0.,  0.]]])}]
```

But I want each matrix to contain diagonals like this:

```
 [[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
  [ 0.,  0.,  1.]]
```

I've tried several variations on this theme to no avail:

`>>> [{'key': np.fill_diagonal(y, 1.0) for y in np.zeros(shape=(4, x,x))} for x in xlist]`

`Out[613]: [{'key': None}, {'key': None}]`

I'm trying to do this with as few for-loops as possible.

Comment: How about `np.repeat(np.eye(3)[None],4,axis=0)`?

Comment: Thank you! I also wrote this uglier line just now which seems to work:

[{'key': np.tril(np.triu(np.ones(shape=(4, x, x)), 0), 0)} for x in xlist]

Comment: You are right, that looks pretty ugly. One more not-so-ugly one : `np.eye(3)[None]*np.ones((4,1,1))`.

Comment: I don't know how all my googling didn't return numpy's eye. Goodness. Thanks again!

Comment: I guess it's just hard to google for these without any established keywords around. Here's a final one : `(np.eye(3)[...,None]*([1]*4)).T`.

Comment: Thanks for following through and being nice about this @Divakar. 
 
This is what I currently have and I'll be playing with the other options you've provided. I'm good to go!

`[{'sigma': np.repeat(np.eye(d_count)[None],4, axis=0)} for x in xlist]`

Have a great day!